# How to use ulimit right

Tags: bash, ulimit

I wanted to limit luakit to a maximum of 150mb virtual memory. Here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#limit virtual memory to 150mb
ulimit -H -v 153600

while true
do
  startx /usr/bin/luakit -U -- -s 0 dpms
done
```

But when memory usage goes above 150mb (in htop VIRT column) nothing happens.

Comment: Try `-d` (data segment size) instead of `-v` (shell's VM allocation)

Comment: how can i check the actual data segment size?

Comment: It should be the total memory usage - the same VIRT column in htop you're referring to.